# Matlab 2015 & Psychtoolbox 3: CenterRect - square not centered

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

This short program is supposed to show a green full-screen background and
a red square of 400 x 400 px in the center. However, the red square is at the top-lef corner `[0, 0, 400, 400]` instead of centered.

```
try
    screens = Screen('Screens'); % check for number of screens (currently '0' because only one screen is connected)
    whichscreen = max(screens);
    [myscreen,rect]=Screen('OpenWindow', whichscreen, [0, 255,0]);
    screen_rect = [0, 0, 1366, 768];
    square_size = [0, 0, 400, 400];
    square_rect = CenterRect(square_size, screen_rect);
    Screen('FillRect', myscreen, [255, 0, 0], square_size);
    Screen('Flip', myscreen);
    KbWait;
    Screen('CloseAll');
catch
    Screen('CloseAll');
end
```

Also, the program doesn't close down on pressing a button on the keyboard.

Any idea what the issue is?

Thanks & best,
J

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong variable. You are drawing a rect to `square_size` and not to `square_rect` as you intend - therefore its obvious that the rect is drawn to `[0, 0, 400, 400]`.

```
try
    screens = Screen('Screens'); % check for number of screens (currently '0' because only one screen is connected)
    whichscreen = max(screens); % 
    [myscreen,rect]=Screen('OpenWindow', whichscreen, [0, 255,0]);
    screen_rect = [0, 0, 1366, 768];
    square_size = [0, 0, 400, 400];
    square_rect = CenterRect(square_size, screen_rect);
    Screen('FillRect', myscreen, [255, 0, 0], square_rect);
    Screen('Flip', myscreen);
    KbWait;
    Screen('CloseAll');
catch
    Screen('CloseAll');
end
```

Additionally you can make it shorter plus compatible to every monitor your using by using the `rect` variable provided by the `Screen('OpenWindow')`.

```
try
    screens = Screen('Screens');
    whichscreen = max(screens);
    [myscreen,rect]=Screen('OpenWindow', whichscreen, [0, 255,0]);
    square_size = [0, 0, 400, 400];
    square_position = CenterRect(square_size, rect);
    Screen('FillRect', myscreen, [255, 0, 0], square_position);
    Screen('Flip', myscreen);
    KbWait;
    Screen('CloseAll');
catch
    Screen('CloseAll');
end
```